# Regex for url make flexible begining

Tags: regex

How to modify the following regex pattern to make it without requiring http or https:

```
<input type="url" 
 pattern="^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\:\'\/\\\+=&amp;%\$#_]*)$"
 validationMessage="Enter a valid web url />
```

User just type into normal www. is ok, not require http:// or https://.

I tried following, and typed into www.google.com, but not working.

```
pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\:\'\/\\\+=&amp;%\$#_]*)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

`pattern="^(?:(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|\/\/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\:\'\/\\\+=&amp;%\$#_]*)$"`

this will let you do for example:

```
http://www.mysite.com
//www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com
```

Comment: Don't say you got a warning.  Tell us what the warning is.  Don't say it doesn't work.  Tell us exactly how it doesn't work.

Comment: well the warning didn't come from the pattern, and all 3 of those match up from the regex shown. So your warning is coming from somewhere else in your code, and whatever "doesn't work" is somewhere else. I think if you want to get to the bottom of it, you're going to have to post the code that actually uses the regex, as well as actual content it is being applied to.

Answer (score 0):

you might trys this:

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\:\'\/\\\+=&amp;%\$#_]*)$
```

That will allow input like:

```
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
https://www.google.com
google.com
```

and will NOT allow stuff like:

```
//www.google.com
```

Hope that is what you looking for.